# What are the syntax differences in Java which a PHP programmer should be aware of?

Tags: java, php, syntax, comparison

I am more practiced in PHP than in Java, and when I use Java I find myself looking at it from a PHP perspective. This can cause trouble, so I'd like to know, the syntax differences between Java and PHP?

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question (though perhaps it ought to have been a community wiki), but unfortunately the close brigade has decided otherwise.

Comment: This belongs in http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not sure about programmers.se, but this is definitely a kind of question that is not suitable for SO **anymore**. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/

Comment: @Matt All I see there is the usual tentative Jeff dicta; the top answers certainly do not agree with him.

Comment: I don't see this as a x-list question. I'm simply looking for information on where the syntax differences in PHP could cause a programmer problems while making a transition to Java programming. The differences are definite and known, just not by me. Maybe I could have rephrased the answer to avoid it being closed. "What are the syntax differences in Java which a PHP programmer should be aware of?".

Comment: @Mohammad: that is a very different question indeed.

Comment: @Matt, the question has been rephrased : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this has been moved to here.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38439/what-are-the-most-common-programming-mistakes-php-programmers-make-in-java